# CoreData subquery with multiple conditions, relationships

Tags: objective-c, core-data, subquery, nspredicate

first time poster, longtime reader/searcher!

I am trying to return information from a Subquery over a one-to-many CoreData relationship.  I have two entities Customers and Messages.  Each customer can have multiple messages.

What I am attempting to do is return the Account number from the Customers table for each customer that has a message of Type "Temp-Stop" with an Effective date less than tomorrow's date.

I tried using combinations of ANY and NONE, without subqueries, but found that they did not work as I wanted.  Finally, I resorted to a subquery.

As I have it below, it returns the Count of customers with past Temp-Stops, but I need the account number of those customers instead.  To be clear, the end goal is to determine if the customer also has a message of Type "Restart" prior to tomorrow's date.  This would mean they are not longer stopped and should be included in a list of active customers.

(Had image here but can't post it because I'm a new user)

```
NSPredicate *predTemps = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(messages, $m, $m.effective < %@ && $m.type == 'Temp Stop').@count > 0", tomorrow];
```

The above predicate returns the number of customers with past Temp-Stops. I have also been able to reference the account number inside the subquery as a third condition, but I want to **return account** numbers, not specify them.

```
NSPredicate *predTemps = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(messages, $m, $m.effective < %@ && $m.type == 'Temp Stop').account", tomorrow];
```

This would be exactly what I want - it does not work though.  I am not clear on how exactly to implement subqueries so maybe there is another solution, as well.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your query is *only* filtering on attributes in the `Message` entity is there a reason you are not running the predicate directly against the `Message` entity instead of its "parent"?

It seems, based on the information in your question, that you could run a `NSFetchRequest` against your `Message` entity and then if you needed information about its parent you could access it through the inverse relationship.

This would give you access to the account via the returned `Message` instances.

Remember, Core Data is an object graph not a database.  So you want to be returning and working with objects (Messages) instead of columns (account).  Once you get the object back you can get the account value out of it.

### UPDATE

This is pseudo code to explain what I mean.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = ...;
NSDate *effectiveDate = ...;
NSError *error = nil;
NSFetchRequest *request = nil;
NSPredicate *pred = nil;

request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Message"];
pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"effective < %@ && type == 'Temp Stop'", effectiveDate];
[request setPredicate:pred];

NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSAssert2(!error || results, @"Error fetching results: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);

NSArray *customers = [results valueForKey:@"customer"];

return customers;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry, I see now that it was not clear in my OP that the name of the relationship is "messages" also.  So I was trying to query it directly...  [Relationships](http://i829.photobucket.com/albums/zz218/jbakerlent/CoreData.png)   I could be misunderstanding your response as well.

Comment: That does not change my answer,  Fetch the Messages.  Then you can get the account information from the Message entity.  Based on your question there is no reason to ever touch the customer entity during the fetch.  Once you have the Message entity you can ask the message for its Customer.

Comment: My understanding was that I was already fetching the messages entity directly with the first subquery.  Basically, I am still (unfortunately) confused on how to return all customers who have a past "Temp-Stop" and a future "Restart".  Thanks again...